# Firefox Dev tools: How to persist calls in network analysis

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug

Since Firebug is outdated with a recent update of Firefox I'm trying to work with the Firefox dev tools. As far as I read these are supposed to replace Firebug.

However there is one option I used frequently in Firebug and haven't found yet in the Dev tools: The persist option in the network analysis.
[image: The persist option in Firebug]

Since I work on a project that uses AJAX Calls to send data and then redirect to another page, I need to persist the calls to analyze them after the redirect. Otherwise the time is far to short to have a look at the data that was send with this call. (This project is for work so this architecture is nothing I could change).

Is there a way to persist the network calls in the Firefox Dev tools?

(I use Firefox 56.0.1 by the way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Settings for the Developer Tools:

[image: Developer Tools Settings Button]

Then select "Enable persistent logs" under "Common Preferences."

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings

Starting from Firefox 57.0 the option got moved from the Settings to the Network panel:

[image: "Persist logs" option in Network Monitor]

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox for Mac, in version 101.0.1, the "Persist Logs" option is now hidden behind the gear icon in the top right of dev tools box.

[image: Firefox developer tools window with Persist Logs option shown in gear icon menu drop-down]